# If statement in Controller not saving changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, controller

I have an if statement in my Controller which decides whether a checkbox is checked or not.

It works fine in the if statement and changes the properties, but when i go to send it back to the view these changes aren't saved.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetUserRights(string userLogin)
{
    if (userLogin != null)
    {
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        var userlogin = manager.GetUserData(userLogin);
        var userrights = userlogin.RightsId.Select(s => new { id = s, text = s });
        var rightdetails = manager.GetAllRightsRows();
        var rightsDetails = from r in rightdetails
                            orderby r.Id
                            select new RightDetail
                            {
                                RightID = r.Id,
                                RightDescription = r.Description,
                                RightName = r.Name,
                                ParentID = r.ParentId,
                                TypeColor = r.TypeColor,
                                Value = r.Value,
                                Checked = false
                            };

        foreach (var userright in userrights)
        {
            foreach (var rightdets in rightsDetails)
            {
                if(rightdets.RightID == userright.id)
                {
                    rightdets.Checked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        return View("_RightsTreeListPartial", rightsDetails); <==== ALL CHECKED 
        PROPERTIES ARE false EVEN THOUGH SOME ARE BEING CHANGED IN THE IF STATEMENT.

    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to bind the `Checked` property using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`?

Comment: It is bound to the Checked column in the `_RightsTreeListPartial` @StephenMuecke

Comment: I cant make sense of your nested `foreach` loops - and your naming makes it impossible :)

Comment: I have a habit of that! What is happening is: `userrights` is getting all rights for a specific user. `rightDetails` is getting all details about rights and putting it into the `RightDetail` model. I then want to change the Checked field from false to true if the user has that right. Hope this clears it up a bit

Comment: So what i need is for each userrights id, change Checked field to true

Comment: In your ajax request are you updating the Partial view area on the main Page: e.g. $('#partialViewArea').html(result);

Comment: No i am updating `('#RightsTreeList_D').html(userrightslist);` which is the table in the partial view, but when i change the `Checked = false` to `Checked = true` in the `select new RightDetail`, when the user clicks, all the boxes are ticked so it is working. The problem is that it is changing the properties from true to false in the if statement but then when i go to send it they are back to false again @DawoodAwan

Comment: @StephenMuecke forgot to tag you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an `IEnumerable`, I am not sure of the reason why, but you cannot edit an item using an `if statement` so the code below is correct and does what it is supposed to, however as it is `IEnumerable` non of the changes are saved, also the process below is very heavy and long winded for what we need to do.

**Original Code**

```
foreach (var userright in userrights)
        {
            foreach (var rightdets in rightsDetails)
            {
                if(rightdets.RightID == userright.id)
                {
                    rightdets.Checked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The new code takes a lot less time and will therefore improve the wait time. Firstly the `IEnumerable` is converted to a `List`, then, using a `for-loop`, the data is iterated through until a match is found, then within an `if statement` the item is changed (using original code and just converting from `IEnumerable` to `List` should work but I wouldn't recommend using it).

**New Code**

```
    var rightdetail = rightsDetails.ToList();
    foreach (var userright in userrights)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < rightdetail.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (rightdetail[i].RightID == userright.id)
            {
                rightdetail[i].Checked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```